# How to set button style in android

Tags: android, button, styles

Normal button looks like:

[image]

Now, please let me know, How can i make a simple button same as an attached image button (i.e. button corner shape is round and also there is no gap between two buttons)

[image]

Comment: Here are some great-looking gradient button examples including a preview: http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

9-patch would work fine here, but I try to avoid them since it's hard for me to do them :(

You can try having a `selector` and using a shape for each state:

The shape would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#AAFFFFFF"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Yes Macarse you were absolutely right about to use 9-patch image, please check my this answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489069/android-button-style/6659516#6659516

Comment: For radius, you can use this little tips if all the corners will be the same : android:radius="Xdp" . Just adding otherwise his code is good.

Answer (score 26):

1- create shapes (with desired colors) for pressed and released states

To create the shapes I would suggest this great website the will do it for you: http://angrytools.com/android/button/

drawable\botton_shape_pressed.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/pressed_button_background"
        android:endColor="@color/pressed_button_background"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

drawable\botton_shape_released.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/released_button_background"
        android:endColor="@color/released_button_background"
        android:angle="45"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

2- create a selector for the two shapes

drawable\botton_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botton_shape_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botton_shape_pressed"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/botton_shape_released" />
</selector>
```

3- use the selector for the button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
    android:onClick="testOnClickListener"
    android:background="@drawable/botton_selector" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) drawable. In order to have no gap (margin) between the buttons you need to create the appropriate layout in XML and set the margin to 0.

Comment: +1, thanx for the support, its also helps me to got the point.

Answer (score 4):

look for foursquared source code and look for SegmentedButton.java file, this is the file that implement these buttons shown in the image.

Comment: +1 Thiago Thanx for the point it out. I have already solved and implemented event better than this :) still i will check it out if it is good. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a Nine patch drawable which is easy with [draw9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) (part of android/tools) and then apply styles and themes... the tutorial at [this link (Androgames.net)](http://blog.androgames.net/40/custom-button-style-and-theme/) should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

to style the text you can add this to the strings.xml

```
    <style name="ButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
    </style>
```

and call it in the main.xml button

```
 style="@style/ButtonText"
```

and an alternative method you can play with is creating in @drawable/btn_black with the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#343434" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#171717" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#343434"
                android:endColor="#171717"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#171717" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ImageView in your xml file and than give onClickable and onFocusable true and then create onClick event method on backend code and give the name of the method on xml , so that instead of dealing with all shape or button issues you just put the imageview there and make it act like a button.Here is sample code for you

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="testClickEvent"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/testImg"/>
```

As I said on backend side create method with sign like this and this will do the job

```
public void testClickEvent(View v){}
```

Then implement what you wanna do in this method

Answer (score 0):

button_primary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@color/background"
            android:startColor="@color/background" />

        <corners android:radius="1dp" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2px"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary3" />

    </shape>
```

call
style="@style/button_primary"