# Android Create Custom UI object, red / green connect button

Tags: android

Good day,

I want to create a new object that i can add to my Android applications View,

I simply want a circle to be displayed red or green depending on whether the network is connected or not. I want a similar look as a radio Button just the colour must change.

Would it be best to just use an image? Or should i create a new view object / component? If so how do i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option:
You can use a PNG image. You need an image in both colors that you want to use. If you like you can create a 9Patch out of your PNGs. 9Patch gives you an image that can be stretched to fit.

Then you use StateList drawable in your XML file. Statelist drawable give you an ability to change an image depending on a state

This is button_statelist.xml in your drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redbutton" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bluebutton" />
</selector>
```

You can use some other state instead of state_pressed

In your layout folder, you define button as:

```
<Button        
       android:id="@+id/button1"        


       android:background="@drawable/button_statelist"      

       />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [android - button style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489069/android-button-style)

Yout can apply style to your button/imagebutton/imageview in which you define how background looks like and border radius to get circle. Save it as your_style.xml in drawable folder. Code looks something like this:

```
      <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#f00" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#d00" />
            <corners
                android:radius="40dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
```

You set the shape and background color with `android:background="@drawable/your_style"`. If you want an extra image (for getting that radio button look) you just add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_overlay_image`.