# How to change style of my buttons by integrating them in a theme?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I used action bar appcompat to genrate a theme here is its code:

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Demostyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_demostyle</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Demostyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_demostyle</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Demostyle</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Demostyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_demostyle</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_demostyle</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_demostyle</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Demostyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Demostyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_demostyle</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Demostyle</item>
</style>
```

Now i want to integrate in this theme style for my buttons. Here is the code that i tried:

```
<style name="ActionBar.Buttons" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Buttons">
<item name="background">@drawable/blue button</item>
</item>
</style>
```

But i get error and it does not work. It gives error about resource not found.
**"@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Buttons"** is the resource it complains about. My question is how can i style my buttons.Here is my screen shot:
[image]

I want the buttnos to be blue too.

Comment: Hi you can see this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12965157/2764682

Comment: I can change style of my buttons but then i am unable to style my action bar.I am asking how can i do both of these things at same time.

Comment: i Have understand you problem, you can't try to change the  buton because the parent style dosn't exist , so you need to create a custom layout with custom style and inflate it in place of you button you can see this exemple , it's a good exemple http://stackoverflow.com/a/19572990/2764682